# ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'flask_session'

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7, flask-session

thank you in advance for the time you will invest in this issue

## the use case

1. I have installed Flask-Session `pip install Flask-Session`
2. I have copy/pasted the tutorial on https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
# Check Configuration section for more details
SESSION_TYPE = 'redis'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/set/')
def set():
    session['key'] = 'value'
    return 'ok'

@app.route('/get/')
def get():
    return session.get('key', 'not set')
```

## the error

```
python flask_session.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "flask_session.py", line 2, in <module>

from flask_session import Session   File "/flask_session.py",

line 2, in <module>
    from flask_session import Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the filename: I renamed the file 'flask_session.py' into 'flask_session_test.py'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is flask_session persists on file-system under a folder named "flask_session" generated in current working directory... offen the same where are our main.
After that Python is unable to locate the right module due to the presence of a flask_session named folder in current path.
To solve this we must delete the folder if exists under our source path and set another name for cache folder, as follows:

```
from flask_session import Session
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = "./flask_session_cache"
Session(app)
```